# How do I fix my PHP password verify code?

Tags: php, html, mysql, passwords, mysql-workbench

I'm having issues with the login check / password verify code of my project. I've implemented code to search the database to look for the data (username/password), but I want to verify that data, and due to the hashing, I think PHP cannot find the data.

The code is placed below, any approaches and advice will be appreciated

```
h2>Administrator Login</h2>
            <form action="adminportal.php" method="post">
                <label>Username</label> <input type="text" name="adminun"/>
                <label>Password</label> <input type="password" name="adminpw"/>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = :username AND password = :password');
$values = [
 'username' => $_POST['adminun'],
 'password' => sha1($_POST['adminun'] . $_POST['adminpw'])
];
$stmt->execute($values);
$user = $stmt->fetch();

if (password_verify($_POST['adminpw'], $user['password'])) {
 $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $user['id'];
}
else {
 echo 'Sorry, your account could not be found';
}
}
```

?>

Comment: What you're using will never work. Don't mix hashing functions and don't concatenate POST arrays.

Comment: your password has no salt, and its attained from DB not input value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select based on the user name only, not the password.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = :username');
$values = [
    'username' => $_POST['adminun'],
];
$stmt->execute($values);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

Then use `password_verify` to verify the posted password against the password from the user record.

```
if (password_verify($_POST['adminpw'], $user['password'])) {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $user['id'];
}
else {
    echo 'Sorry, your account could not be found';
}
```

This will only work if the password stored in the database was hashed with `password_hash`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your sql should select base on username only first like this

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = :username');
$values = [
    'username' => $_POST['adminun'],
];
$stmt->execute($values);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

then use password_verify() to verify the password